# Why Poisson's equation is important?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

The Poisson equation can be deduced by Newton's mechanics:
$$\Delta \Phi =-4\pi G\sigma$$

Einstein tried to give a *"Poisson's equation"* that works with his theory. 
This equation seems to be important. Why??

Comment: It is a PDE that determines the gravitational field given the mass distribution in space. How does that not seem important to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its most basic form, Poisson's equation is
$$\nabla^2\phi=f$$
This can be applied to Newtonian gravity, electrostatics, and more.

Most importantly, though, it implies that if - in the case of gravity - you know the density distribution in a region of space, you know the potential in that region of space. You can then use this to figure out how a particle can move.

That is an incredibly powerful tool.

The Einstein field equations should look a lot like the Poisson equation. On the right side you have the term describing the "source" of the interaction, and on the left side you have its results.